# Destroy PushNotification in CustomApplication with Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api

Good morning,

I've been trying to delete PushNotification setup for a CustomApplication with the Metadata API (version 46.0 ) but although the answer is successful the changes are not done in my developer organization.

Manual access to push notification:

> Salesforce Classic >> Setup >> Create >> Apps >> "My app" >> Choose Push Notifications >> Select objects and fields for notifications

**Use case**

1. Deploy a CustomApplication with some PushNotification setup. Example of CustomApplication Metadata xml:

```
[...]
<consoleConfig>
[...]
    <pushNotifications>
        <fieldNames>Account</fieldNames>
        <objectName>Case</objectName>
    </pushNotifications>
[...]
</consoleConfig>
[...]
```

2. Deploy the same CustomApplication removing all PushNotifications. Example of CustomApplication Metadata xml:

```
[...]
<consoleConfig>
[...]
    <!-- All tags of pushNotifications had been removed -->
[...]
</consoleConfig>
[...]
```

**Expected**

All the push notifications are removed from the developer organization

[image]

**Actual**

All the push notifications are NOT removed from the developer organization

[image: Push notifications]

**Question**

- Is it possible to complete remove all PushNotification from CustomApplication using Salesforce Metadata API?
- If it is possible, please could you let me know how?

Comment: The problem is that SF counts null list in update metadata xml as that you do not want to do anything with this component. However, it's completely different with existing, but empty list, than it withdraw all notifications. I just don't know how to set up empty, not null, list in xml format.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the same issue in API 47.0 in various ways:

1. Removing all the push notifications tags as you did
2. Trying to keep the tags but leaving blanks as values for the different tags (`<objectName> </objectName>, <pushNotifications> </pushNotifications>`)
3. Specifying null in the tags
4. Trying to make the different tags empty (`<pushNotifications />, <objectName />, <fieldNames />`)

I either get an error that *Required field is missing: fieldNames* or *Invalid Push Notifications: .*

The only thing that works is to deploy new push notifications and remove the old ones at the same time.

However, that doesn't really solve the issue at hand if you want to remove all at once. I'd suggest a Salesforce case to confirm, but I'd take an educated guess that you cannot remove push notifications completely from a custom app through the metadata API.